# How to avoid error warning in dynamic chart if we use zero values and #N/A?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016, vba

I have a problem in running my dynamic chart. I use zero values and #N/A in my chart because it is important to be able to illustrate my data. Zero values indicate the dry period and I use #N/A in order to make gaps in my chart, because if I use zero, it will draw chart in zero values.

I made formula for my dynamic chart by using OFFSET Formula and then use it to my dynamic chart.
My formula is like :
WaterLevelSeries: =OFFSET(Datafeeds1!$L$18,0,0,COUNTA(Datafeeds!$L:$L)-1)

and then I change the series data in the graph so that it use this "WaterLevelSeries" formula.

My data is about dry period and the peak flow, so to distinguish between those two, it is important to define zero values for the chart. However there is a warning I received like this :
[warning error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bDw2.png)

and when I tracked it with "F5 then Go to Special" and ticked "Formula", it seems that my excel sheet did not like zero values and #N/A because it highlights my cells that contain those values. 
However since I really need zero values and this #N/A in my dynamic chart, is there a way to inactivate the error warning? I  tried the option menu in excel (Options - Formulas - unchecked all the Error Formulas Rule), but it did not work. The warning still appeared.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What was that warning? What was that "menu option" you tried? Please [edit] that into your question along with details (like formula) of the cells that gave the error.

Comment: Hi @HansKesting I've edited my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the IFERROR function?

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/iferror.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However the answer is really different with my question. I need to use #N/A in order to draw gaps in my dynamic chart.

Answer (score 0):

Your image shows that you tried the function

```
=IF(F18>0;4;#N/A)
```

Excel probably trips over that "#N/A".

So use the [NA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NA-function-5469c2d1-a90c-4fb5-9bbc-64bd9bb6b47c) `NA()`

```
=IF(F18>0;4;NA())
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel charts ignore data cells with ANY text in it so suggest you use something other than #N/A.

=IF(F18>0;4;"-")

Hope that helps